# Cannot redirect subdirectory to ssl

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Why won't this `.htaccess` force all subdirectories to use SSL?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

My particular use case: I have WordPress installed in a subdirectory, and I'm using `mod_rewrite` to "hide" that from my site visitors (docs are stored in `example.com/wordpress`, but appear to the browser as `example.com`).  All good there.  I added the HTTPS rewrite per instructions found in countless posts.  But when I browse to `example.com/nextcloud`, all files are served up via HTTP!

There is an `.htaccess` file in my `/nextcloud` subdirectory.  The only section pertaining to `mod_rewrite` reads as follows:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
  RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta\.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^\.well-known/carddav /remote.php/dav/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^\.well-known/caldav /remote.php/dav/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^remote/(.*) remote.php [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates)/.* - [R=404,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*
  RewriteRule ^(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console).* - [R=404,L]
```

I only have a very basic knowledge of `.htaccess` files, but my understanding is that it works top-down (`.htaccess` in subdirectories can overwrite the settings of higher directories) *except* for `mod_rewrite`, which is a special case and works in the opposite fashion (the topmost directory takes precedence).

If my understanding is true, why is my code not working?

Comment: So, to the outside world, nextcloud should be served from its subdirectory, but the WordPress site should be served from the root? If so, there's an easy solution.

Comment: @Walf That is correct; that is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In your `/.htaccess`, add this above all other conditions/rules:

```
RewriteRule ^nextcloud(?:$|/) - [L]
```

That prevents WordPress from ever getting the requests.

In your `/nextcloud/.htaccess`, set

```
RewriteBase /nextcloud/
```

Also, shouldn't your root base should be just `/` since that is the public path to WordPress? How do static files route correctly? E.g. how does `example.com/real/file` get to `example.com/wordpress/real/file`?